# How create a ordered pair function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, for-loop, dynamic

I come from Matlab and I want code a function to create a ordered pair function.

example:

Array1=[2,5,7];
Array2 = [6,2];

PairOrdered = [ 2,6 ; 2,2 ; 5,6 ; 5,2 ; 7,6 ; 7,2];

In Matlab I use this logic:

```
LA=length(A);
LB=length(B);
LT= LA*LB;

M = zeros(LT,2);

for i = 1:LA

for j =1:LB

    M((i-1)*LB+j , : ) = [A(i),B(j)];

end
end
```

As you can see, I define a pair ordered matrix with the length of the two arrays. In Python I use the same logic like this:

```
A = [1,2,3,4];
B = [5,6,7];

LA = len(A)
LB = len(B)

Maux = [];

for i in A:
for j in B:

    Maux[(i-1)*LB+j , j]
```

The system say this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users---\Desktop\Code1\ParOrde.py", line 17, in
> Maux[(i-1)*LB+j , j]
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

How I can create a dynamic matrix type integers? Or how I fix this?

Comment: `for i in A` assigns each of the values in `A` to `i`, not their indices. Instead do `for i in range(len(A))`. Also, you can’t index out of bounds in Python, AFAIK. You’d have to preallocate the array with `A = np.zeros(len(A)*len(B))`. This requires `import numpy as np`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is `itertools.product()` to give you the product of those two lists:

```py
import itertools
Array1 = [2,5,7]
Array2 = [6,2]
Array1_Array2 = list(itertools.product(Array1, Array2))
print(Array1_Array2)
```

If you were keen on doing it yourself you might use a comprehension:

```py
Array1 = [2,5,7]
Array2 = [6,2]
Array1_Array2 = [(a, b) for a in Array1 for b in Array2]
print(Array1_Array2)
```

or via traditional `for` loops:

```py
Array1 = [2,5,7]
Array2 = [6,2]
Array1_Array2 = []
for a in Array1:
    for b in Array2:
        Array1_Array2.append((a,b))
print(Array1_Array2)
```

All three will give you a list of tuples:

```
[(2, 6), (2, 2), (5, 6), (5, 2), (7, 6), (7, 2)]
```

Though casting the tuples themselves to lists is trivial if you wanted that.

If you are going to be doing a munch of "matrix" like stuff, you might want to check out the `numpy` package.

Implemented as a function, it might look like:

```py
def OrderPair(A,B):
    return [[a, b] for a in A for b in B]

A1 = [2,5,7]
A2 = [6,2]
S = OrderPair(A1, A2)
print(S)
```

Giving you:

```
[[2, 6], [2, 2], [5, 6], [5, 2], [7, 6], [7, 2]]
```